# insert table data from another table having same data in column

Tags: sql

i have two tables **Order** & **Bill**

i have data in **Order** Table as

```
OrderID      EmpID      Bill
-------------------------------   
1            1          40
2            1          20
3            1          30
4            2          50
5            2          60
6            3          100
```

i want to insert data in **Bill** Table
data should be looks like

```
  BillID      EmpID      Bill
    -------------------------------   
    1           1          90
    2           2          110
    3           3          100
```

in short i want to collaps data according to **EmpID**
please suggest SQL Query.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why tagged as "model-view-controller"  ?

Comment: because i am going to implement in mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select MIN(OrderID),EmpID,Sum(BIll) from Order group by EmpID
```

and if u want to insert data into Bill table

```
Insert into Bill(BillId,EmpID, Bill) select MIN(OrderID),EmpID,Sum(BIll) from Order group by EmpID
```

Comment: i want this query in lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

**First add this class**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public int BIll { get; set; }
}
```

**Than add this method.**

```
public IActionResult Error()
        {
            List<MyClass> db = new List<MyClass>();

            db.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                OrderID = 1,
                EmpID = 1,
                BIll = 40

            });
            db.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                OrderID = 2,
                EmpID = 1,
                BIll = 20

            });
            db.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                OrderID = 3,
                EmpID = 1,
                BIll = 30

            });

            db.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                OrderID = 4,
                EmpID = 2,
                BIll = 50

            });

            db.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                OrderID = 5,
                EmpID = 2,
                BIll = 60

            }); db.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                OrderID = 6,
                EmpID = 3,
                BIll = 100

            });


            var query = db.GroupBy(x => x.EmpID).Select(x => new
            {
                EmpID = x.Key,
                BIll = x.Sum(x1 => x1.BIll),
            });
            return View();
        }
```